# How can I use the values from Tooltip and do simple math with it?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am using a windows form and have a line chart. I have a tooltip with the following code:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);`
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);

    chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = getLegendName(legendOne) + "\n" + info;

    if (chart1.Series.IndexOf(legendTwo) == 1)
    {
        chart1.Series[1].ToolTip = getLegendName(legendTwo) + "\n" + info;
    }
    if (chart1.Series.IndexOf(legendThree) == 2)
    {
        chart1.Series[2].ToolTip = getLegendName(legendThree) + "\n" + info;
    }
    if (chart1.Series.IndexOf(legendFour) >= 3)
    {
        chart1.Series[3].ToolTip = getLegendName(legendFour) + "\n" + info;
    }
}
```

I now wish to click whenever the tool tip were to pop-up so that I may get the Y-Value. I want to do it TWICE so I can take the difference between the 2nd point and the 1st to find the overall difference between 2 certain points.

```
private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (diffCounter == 0)
    {
        valXOne = "#VALX";
        Console.WriteLine("VALX " + valXOne);
        diffCounter++;
    }
    if (diffCounter == 1)
    {
        valXTwo = "#VALX";
        diffCounter++;
    }
    diffCounter = 0;

    double xOne = 0;
    double xTwo = 0;

    if (double.TryParse(valXOne, out double resultOne))
    {
        xOne = resultOne;
    }

    if (double.TryParse(valXTwo, out double resultTwo))
    {
        xTwo = resultTwo;
    }

    pointDifferenceTextBox.Text = (Math.Abs(xTwo - xOne)).ToString();
}
```

My current code DOES NOT work but I tried to make it somewhere along the lines where it would. I just don't know how to read values from the tooltip. Tooltip understands the string "#VALX" but a normal string does not of course. How can I access or read this value for my variable valXONE?

Comment: Your HitTest tells you if you hit a DataPoints and if so its index. so now you can directly read x- and y-values. No need to care about the ToolTip!

Comment: You can subscribe to the `Popup` event of the `ToolTip`.  If you store your results from `chart1_MouseMove` you can retrieve them from your event handler.

Comment: Not sure if chart's built-in tooltips do have that event.. - Also _My current code DOES NOT work_ Well that doesn't help. Tell us what works and how exactly the rest doesn't work! - Also: If you use MouseClick you can directly access the location and do another hittest, if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to acccess the `Tooltip` Text in your case.

Simply use a `HitTest` to determine the point you are hitting and read its values directly!

This would be where the ToolTip expression would get the "#VALX" from anyway.

Here is a corrected version of your click event:

```
int diffCounter = 0;
double xOne = 0;
double xTwo = 0;

private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (result.PointIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (diffCounter == 0)
        {
            xOne = result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].XValue;
            diffCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine("VALX 2 " + xOne  );

        }
        else if (diffCounter == 1)
        {
            xTwo = result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].XValue;
            diffCounter = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("VALX 1 " + xTwo  );
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Delta = " +( xTwo - xOne) );
    }
}
```

Note that besides the automated expression values you can also set fixed values to each `DataPoint.ToolTip`. These may be of interest and you would pick them up from that property directly.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm looking for and it works but I'm only getting 0's returned. I want to compare my Y-Values or the y-axis numbers. My X-axis are all strings (or DataTimes) actually so isn't the "XValue" for those?

Comment: That's right. If you add the x-values as string they are lost. Do yourself a favor and add them as DateTimes! You can still use a format string to style the axis labels.. If you actually are interested in the Y-Values simply pull out these (`YValues[0]` probably). If your data points are not dens you may want the axis values. In that case, say so and I'll update the answer..

Comment: Got it! Used YValues[0] and worked perfectly. Thanks!